# Fatal error in, line 0 -- Fatal JavaScript invalid size error 171211145

Tags: javascript, reactjs, visual-studio-code, fatal-error

I'm working on an app with friends right now. (We're using Github) All of a sudden, I get an error message that my friends don't have.

I'm getting this error message in VS Code:

```
    Fatal error in , line 0
    Fatal JavaScript invalid size error 171211145
    # #
    # #
    # #
    # #FailureMessage Object: 00000080DCFFEAB0
    1: 00007FF6FA101B7F node_api_throw_syntax_error+203775
    2: 00007FF6FA012B2F v8::CTypeInfoBuilder<void>::Build+11951
    3: 00007FF6FAE82CF2 V8_Fatal+162
    4: 00007FF6FA9C4A55 v8::internal::FactoryBase<v8::internal::Factory>::NewFixedArray+101
    5: 00007FF6FA84A0D3 v8::internal::FeedbackNexus::ic_state+65795
    6: 00007FF6FA868C50 v8::debug::Script::GetIsolate+15600
    7: 00007FF6FA6B53B0 v8::internal::CompilationCache::IsEnabledScriptAndEval+25952
    8: 00007FF6FABC1E81 v8::internal::SetupIsolateDelegate::SetupHeap+558193
    9: 00007FF67B1C37BB
```

I haven't done anything yet, because I don't know what I can do.

Comment: Would anything in [this issue](https://github.com/nodejs/help/issues/3728#issuecomment-1050127484) be relevant to you?

Comment: How can I find out which line of code is causing the too large array?

Comment: In addition, I have already checked if the react-scripts in devDependencies package.json are in it and yes they are.

Comment: add log breakpoints along the execution path to locate the line that cause it,

Answer (score 0):

There could be several reasons why the error occurs.

1. Node version. Ask friends what version they are on, and try to use the same
2. Broken `node_modules`. Delete the `node_modules` directory and run `npm install` (or `yarn install` or `pnpm install`)
3. Broken git. Delete the local project directory and clone it again. Remember to save all your changes (i.e. `git branch -b stage && git add . && git commit -m "stage changes" && git push -u origin stage`)
4. One cure for all diseases - restart your computer